# How can I search playframework JPA entities without sacrificing good performance?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, playframework, full-text-search

I'm using playframework 1.2.4 and JPA for persistent storage.  In the [playframework documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/jpa#Findusingasimplifiedquery) there are many references of using the "like" operator to find entities.  I can see using this  for a search operation, but because the "like" operator does a full table scan, this is going to be really slow as I have more and more entities.  In other words, it doesn't scale.  What is a scalable way to search for entities efficiently?  I know that Mysql has a FullText feature to solve this problem, but how can I access this feature using JPA in playframework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try elasticsearch module, which support JPA very well.
http://www.playframework.org/modules/elasticsearch